# How to place and number 3 short equations in one line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I have 3 short equations which consume much vertical space, if each one is typeset in a separate line.

- How can I **typeset them in one line** in a **"mathematically correct"** way?
  I do not necessarily need separate labels for each one of them: one label (and equation number would be enough)

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{array, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
x_{1} &= & \frac{A-A_{0}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left( A_{\mathrm{A}} - A_{\mathrm{a}} \right)}
\label{exv:eqn:UmrechnungEingangsgroesse1} \\
x_{2} &= & \frac{B-B_{0}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left( B_{\mathrm{A}} - B_{\mathrm{a}} \right)}
\label{exv:eqn:UmrechnungEingangsgroesse2} \\
x_{3} &= &  \frac{C-C_{0}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left( C_{\mathrm{A}} - C_{\mathrm{a}} \right)}
\label{exv:eqn:UmrechnungEingangsgroesse3}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, [Avoid `eqnarray`](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/).

You can use a normal `equation` environment and separate the equations with a `\qquad`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x_{1} = \frac{A-A_{0}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left( A_{\mathrm{A}} - A_{\mathrm{a}} \right)}
\qquad
x_{2} = \frac{B-B_{0}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left( B_{\mathrm{A}} - B_{\mathrm{a}} \right)}
\qquad
x_{3} =  \frac{C-C_{0}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left( C_{\mathrm{A}} - C_{\mathrm{a}} \right)}
\label{exv:eqn:UmrechnungEingangsgroesse3}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(In my original answer I used an `align` environment, but this isn't really "correct", as that is meant for aligning equations over more than one line. As this only has one line, it is more appropriate to use an `equation` environment, as commented by Andrew Stacey.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint on eqnarray and for your example! Is that "mathematically correct"? Should(n't) I use a kind of separator (like semicolon) between the 3 equations?

Comment: @Martin To be honest, I don't know what is common practice here, sorry.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T.: thanks for your honesty! So I hope there'll drop in some mathematicians which can tell us. :-)

Comment: (I am a mathematician.)  In this case, I'd say that the whitespace is enough separation.  I've tried with commas and semi-colons and they just get lost - they're so small with respect to the fractions that they look more like stray pixels that have lost their way.

Comment: Incidentally, why are you using `align` and not `equation`?  There's nothing to align with.  Using `\qquad` between the pieces produces adequate separation, I deem.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Good point about `align`, I was actually questioning my own judgment on that one a little. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 21):

Firstly, I fully support the points avoiding `eqnarray` and using `amsmath` environments whenever possible, such as `align`.

`amsmath` provides a `subequations` environment, which might also be useful, though it's more for numbering subequations but not for lining up horizontally.

You could use `align` such as Torbjørn showed, as it supports several columns. Here the `&` symbol is both for alignment and for separating columns, as in tabular, alternating.

Another option is `flalign`, you could use it in the very same way, but the equations would be more spread out, so you would have more space.

You don't need to use a `amsmath` align environment, since the horizontal positioning is a tabular like issue. So if you would like to have equations with labels you can refer to, you could use for example `tabularx` with equal column width:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Equations}
See equations \eqref{eqn:1}, \eqref{eqn:2} and \eqref{eqn:3}.

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  \begin{equation}
  x_{1} = \frac{A-A_{0}}{\frac{1}{2}
    \cdot \left( A_{\mathrm{A}} - A_{\mathrm{a}} \right)}
    \label{eqn:1}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
  x_{2} = \frac{B-B_{0}}{\frac{1}{2}
    \cdot \left( B_{\mathrm{A}} - B_{\mathrm{a}} \right)}
    \label{eqn:2}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
  x_{3} = \frac{C-C_{0}}{\frac{1}{2}
    \cdot \left( C_{\mathrm{A}} - C_{\mathrm{a}} \right)}
    \label{eqn:3}
  \end{equation}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: three equations in a row]

Comment: thanks, a `tabularx` is also a good idea - I would also  accept your answer if I could, but I'll go with the `\qquad` this time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if I want, say 2 columns of 4 equations each and I try to use `align` rather than `equation`.  *ERROR: Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \align.* Any suggestions?

Comment: My equations are not aligned vertically when I do this (one has a fraction and the other doesn't).  I've tried centering the text as described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104544/vertically-center-text-in-tabularx-table/105671#105671  However, it still is not perfectly aligned due to the presence of the fraction in one but not the other.  Any suggestions?