# Vertically center text in tabularx table

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

How to center text vertically in this table?

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | c | X | X | }
    \hline
      \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Sign} \\
    \hline
      31.03.2013 & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
```

Changing package is not a solution for me. How to do it in tabularx?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
```

defines the `X` column to use `m` (`\parbox[c]`) instead of `p` (`parbox[t]`).

Comment: How would this be used in the OP's example?

Comment: @beldaz just put that line anywhere before the table

Comment: Ah, understood. I was trying to figure out how to make a single column vertically centred, not all of them, hence my confusion.