# Vertical alignment in tabularx X column type

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I'd like to create a new column type which works exactly like a X column from `tabularx` but that also has the text vertically centered. I tried with the `newcolumntype` command but I can't figure out where to put the second column type? Example:

```
\newcolumntype{n}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

Where should I put the `m`to specify that the cells content should be vertically centered?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The example in the `tabularx` documentation is

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
```

Then use `X` as usual.

Comment: but is it possible with the newcolumntype command?

Comment: @franz no, you can't turn a `p` column into an `m` column with `\newcolumntype`.

Comment: In what way does this Q&A differ from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105671/27721 ?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty The other question gives a working example