# What is the correct way to stretch the cell keeping it vertically centred in tabularX

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I have this table, in which the text is touching the horizontal lines above and below, I tried some of the solutions to stretch the cells I found in the web. I managed to stretch the cell but I can't keep it center aligned.

This would be a MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{mathabx} 
\everymath{\displaystyle}
     \usepackage{tabularx}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{1.3\textwidth}{ c | X }
                \hline 
                    Objetivos de diseño & $\frac{W_{TO}}{S_w} $, $\frac{T_{TO}}{W_{TO}} $, $A$, $C_{Do}$, $\varphi$, $N_e$, $C_{Lmax_{TO}}$, $C_{Lmax_{L}}$, $C_{Lmax}$ \\\hline 
                    Especificaciones iniciales &  $\frac{W_{CR}}{W_{TO}}$, $\frac{W}{W_{TO}}$, $\frac{W_{L}}{W_{TO}}$, $q$, $\sigma$, $S_{TO}$, $S_e$, $n$ \\\hline
                    Factores adicionales & $\frac{T_{TO}}{T_2} $, $\gamma$, $\eta$, $c_T$, $\frac{T_{TO}}{T_{CR}} $\\  \hline
            \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: The cells that are touching the horizontal rules are not centred (since they're in an `X`-column). Do you want them centred?

Comment: @Werner I want them vertically centered, I know the X column doen't vertically center cells but I didn't want add more code since I don't know how to properly do this

Comment: Use something like `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<num>}` (as suggested in [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764)) and update the `X`-column to use an `m`-type column instead of the default `p`-type column (as suggested in [Vertical alignment in `tabularx` `X`-column type](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113020/5764)). That is, `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying `arraystretch` doesn't produce vertically centred cells. I propose a solution based on the `cellspace` package: it defines minimal distances between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell or line, and betwen the bottom of a cell and the top of the below cell/line. One has to use the pre-qualifier `S` before the qualifier. By default it works with the usual qualifiers `l,c,r, p{}, m{}, b{}`, and we may add the `X` qualifier.

I also use the `makecell` package, in order to have horizontal rules of variable thickness.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1.3\textwidth}{ l!{\vrule width1pt}>{$}S{X}<{$}}
            \Xhline{1pt}
                Objetivos de diseño & \frac{W_{TO}}{S_w} , \frac{T_{TO}}{W_{TO}} , A, C_{Do}, φ, N_e, C_{Lmax_{TO}}, C_{Lmax_{L}}, C_{Lmax} \\
\hline
Especificaciones iniciales & \frac{W_{CR}}{W_{TO}}, \frac{W}{W_{TO}}, \frac{W_{L}}{W_{TO}}, q, σ, S_{TO}, S_e, n \\\hline
Factores adicionales & \frac{T_{TO}}{T_2} , γ, η, c_T, \frac{T_{TO}}{T_{CR}} \\
            \Xhline{1pt}
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does the job, however I have trouble making it work with work other packages I really need. Namely `xcolor`, `colortbl` and `pgfplots`. When I load these, it works with the usual qualifiers `l,c,r` but not with `p{}, m{}, b{}, X`

Comment: @piptin: do you mean with these packages it doesn't add any vertical spacing? I suppose you use macros from these packages in your tables?

Comment: no, actually, just adding the packages to preamble is enough for the spacing to disappear, but only for the columns types `p{}, m{}, b{}, X`, for the others works

Comment: I hadn't thought of testing that. I was aware of problems with the `matrix*`environments (from `mathtools`) for which the package author wrote a workaround. I'll report him this problem.

Comment: @piptin: A workaround could be to have an `Sl` qualifier for the first column, with sufficiently great value for the minima — I tested with `12pt` which seems acceptable. Of course it's only a workaround, to be adapted  depending on your real table.

Comment: for this case I think it's better to use the qualifier in a c column for the second one, since the X column is not really needed here

Comment: If you don't need multiline cells, it' perfect: the simpler, the better;).

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx} 
 \usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.7}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X }
            \hline 
                Objetivos de diseño & $\frac{W_{TO}}{S_w} $, $\frac{T_{TO}}{W_{TO}} $, $A$, $C_{Do}$, $\varphi$, $N_e$, $C_{Lmax_{TO}}$, $C_{Lmax_{L}}$, $C_{Lmax}$ \\\hline 
                Especificaciones iniciales &  $\frac{W_{CR}}{W_{TO}}$, $\frac{W}{W_{TO}}$, $\frac{W_{L}}{W_{TO}}$, $q$, $\sigma$, $S_{TO}$, $S_e$, $n$ \\\hline
                Factores adicionales & $\frac{T_{TO}}{T_2} $, $\gamma$, $\eta$, $c_T$, $\frac{T_{TO}}{T_{CR}} $\\  \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: @piptin globally setting `\everymath{\displaystyle}` rarely makes good results, are you sure ypu want that? anyeway if ypu set it for this table then just increas `\arraystretch` more if needed, or alternatively set each entry in the second column as a _single_ display using `\[....\]` rather than a sequence of inline `$xx..$` ...

Comment: I really want that, but I tried it again and now it works in the MWE. I just can't seem to get it to work in my document. I'll try to look for the problem.

Comment: @piptin there are centuries of typesetting tradition indicating inline math should be set differently to display math... (the example you have here is different: it is "really" a display, so setting it locally is reasonably if you choose to use `$` rather than `\[`

Comment: I did't know you could put a math environment inside a table, good to know. I'll try to use inline math where it should be then :)

Comment: I'm going to remove this as the answer since it really doesn't centre vertically the cells, it only adds space above. I had a typo after every line in the table there was a `\\[15pt]` so it looked centred

Answer (score 1):

You can add a strut using an invisible rule:

```
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule[-12pt]{0pt}{30pt}}  %% adjust -12pt and 30pt as you wish
```

and add it in `>{\mystrut} c`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule[-12pt]{0pt}{30pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1.3\textwidth}{>{\mystrut} c | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X }
            \hline
                Objetivos de diseño & $\frac{W_{TO}}{S_w} $, $\frac{T_{TO}}{W_{TO}} $, $A$, $C_{Do}$, $\varphi$, $N_e$, $C_{Lmax_{TO}}$, $C_{Lmax_{L}}$, $C_{Lmax}$ \\\hline
                Especificaciones iniciales &  $\frac{W_{CR}}{W_{TO}}$, $\frac{W}{W_{TO}}$, $\frac{W_{L}}{W_{TO}}$, $q$, $\sigma$, $S_{TO}$, $S_e$, $n$ \\\hline
                Factores adicionales & $\frac{T_{TO}}{T_2} $, $\gamma$, $\eta$, $c_T$, $\frac{T_{TO}}{T_{CR}} $\\  \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this looks nice and easy and clean, but it really doesn't vertically align the cell, you have to play with the strut dimension to get it vertically aligned