# Vertically align text in tabularx environment

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I tried the different approaches I have found here on TexExchange. But I wasn't successful. I'm not sure whether the embedded figure leads to that behavior. I want to align the all the text centered or on top, to make it looking better. My current table looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llll}
        \bfseries Label & \bfseries Membership- & \bfseries Parameters & \bfseries Graph \\
         & \bfseries Function & [m] & \bfseries \\
        \hline
        \textbf{\emph{near}} & trapezoidal & $\{0.3, 0.75\}$ & \includegraphics[height=3.75cm]{03_Figures/05_fuzzy_distance_near.eps} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{\emph{medium}} & trapezoidal & $\{0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5\}$ & \includegraphics[height=3.75cm]{03_Figures/05_fuzzy_distance_medium.eps} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{\emph{far}} & trapezoidal & $\{1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0\}$ & \includegraphics[height=3.75cm]{03_Figures/05_fuzzy_distance_far.eps} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{\emph{very far}} & trapezoidal & $\{2.5, 4.0\}$ & \includegraphics[height=3.75cm]{03_Figures/05_fuzzy_distance_veryfar.eps} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \caption{Input Fuzzy Sets for Distance}
    \label{tab:fuzzySetDistance}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table with figure]

Comment: It's not clear what has to be centred. The column  heads?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113021/89976 while changing to `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXm{4cm}}`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is that graphic files a laid on the base line of the row, hence they're bottom-aligned. To have them top-aligned with the row, use

```
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=3.75cm]{03_Figures/05_fuzzy_distance_near.eps}}
```

and similarly for all figures.

To have them vertically centred, use

```
 \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=3.75cm]{03_Figures/05_fuzzy_distance_near.eps}}
```

Also, similar to Runar Trollet's suggestion, use the preamble

```
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
```

otherwise, there's no reason to use `tabularx`.