# How to align horizontally the rows between X type columns?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I have a table with short and long headings. I'm using tha column type `X` from the `tabularx` package. The headings are aligned to the top, how can I align the headings horizontally in the middle?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
\textbf{Short heading\newline(units)} &
\textbf{This is a long long, very very long heading\newline(units)}\\%
\midrule
416,09 & 194,30 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I removed the `align` tag because `align` refers specifically to a multi-line math display, not general alignment questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to achieve horizontally and vertically centered entries you can use the following redefinition of `X` type columns. Normally they are derived from `p` type columns that are top aligned. With `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` we can change that so that `x` type columns are derived from the vertically centered `m` type columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
\textbf{Short heading\newline(units)} &
\textbf{This is a long long, very very long heading\newline(units)}\\%
\midrule
416,09 & 194,30 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use horizontally and vertically centered `X` type columns more often throughout your document, you could also add `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` to your preamble and use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*2{Y}}`.

---

If you wish to keep the original definition of top aligned `X` type columns and have a separate derived and vertically cerntered column type, you might want to have a look at [Copy tabularx X column as new vertically centered column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454801/134144)

---

If you only want to change the vertical alignment for a single table, you could use the following local redefinition of the `X` type column. Here I have added `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` just after `\begin{table}` of the corresponding table.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
\textbf{Short heading\newline(units)} &
\textbf{This is a long long, very very long heading\newline(units)}\\%
\midrule
416,09 & 194,30 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb]
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
\textbf{Short heading\newline(units)} &
\textbf{This is a long long, very very long heading\newline(units)}\\%
\midrule
416,09 & 194,30 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
\textbf{Short heading\newline(units)} &
\textbf{This is a long long, very very long heading\newline(units)}\\%
\midrule
416,09 & 194,30 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It will bee affect all the tables. What I have to do if I want to modify only one table?

Comment: @DanielValenciaC - In that case, don't issue the instruction `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` in the preamble. Instead, issue it immediately after `\begin{table}[htb]`.