# Centre cell vertically in tabularx across multiple multiline rows

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, multirow

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{llX}
  \multirow{2}{*}{A} & B & \lipsum[1][1-2] \\
                     & C & \lipsum[2][1-3]\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

I have used [Vertical alignment in tabularx X column type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113020/vertical-alignment-in-tabularx-x-column-type?answertab=active#tab-top) to centre cells vertically.

However, I am not pleased the way "A" is centred. It uses `multirow`. How to centre "A" vertically in the middle of the table?

Solution that avoids the use of `multirow` is also accepted.

Comment: Maybe you can try with `\multirow{8}{*}{A}`.

Comment: Since you made `m` the underlying column type, since the cells in column 3 occupy 12 rows in all, and since one half of 12 is 6, you should replace `\multirow{2}{*}{A}` with `\multirow{6}{*}{A}`.

Comment: @Mico: Wouldn't one typically use `\multirow{12}` in order to vertically center a cell adjacent to a cell that contains 12 lines of text? However, in the OP's case the redefinition of the `X` type column using `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` seems to interfere with that.

Comment: @leandriis, then I need to manually count rows. So laborious when dealing with many tables, changing text.

Comment: @leandriis - Indeed, if the `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` directive weren't there, one would have to use `12`, not `6`, as the first argument of `\multirow`.

Comment: @Mico, I checked using `\multirow{6}...`. There were 4 rows above and 5 below "A" - centring was not done nicely. `7` appear to do the job.

Comment: @Viesturs - The screenshot you posted shows a total of 12 rows, not 9 rows, for the cells in column 3.  Using the code you posted, I also arrive at a total of 12 rows, not 9. Using your code and `\multirow{6}...`, the letter `A` is placed very nicely between the cells of column 3. Speaking purely aesthetically, that's exactly where the letter `A` belongs. Of course, if you've changed the code for the cells in column 3 in the meantime, there is absolutely no reason to believe that `6` will continue to be the appropriate argument for the first argument of `\multirow`.

Answer (score 3):

As Ulrike said in a comment, to avoid manual adjustment, nesting `tabular`s could be a solution.

I would put a `tabular` with an `m` column of appropriate width in the main `tabular`.

I added the lines just to show the "A" is vertically centered.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|ll}
\hline
  A & 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lm{.352\linewidth}@{}}
        B & \lipsum[1][1-2]\\
        C & \lipsum[2][1-3]\\
    \end{tabular}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{4ex}\noindent\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{|llX}
    \hline
    A & B & Just for benchmark\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In case of multiple multirow cells nesting in a nesting would be required.

Comment: @Viesturs Yes, it may be

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possibe solution using a `minipage` and a `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{2em}
A
\end{minipage}%
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth-2em}{lX}
   B & \lipsum[1][1-2]  \\
   C & \lipsum[2][1-3]\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use a 1-row multicolumn as the baseline of the m-column is there. In other cases you will have to use the vmode-option described in the documentation. Imho while multirow works okay with 1-line cells it is imho rather a pain with m- and p-columns and I use it seldom.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
% with X as p-column 5 works:
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{llX}
  \multirow{5}{*}{A} & B & \lipsum[1][1-2] \\
                     & C & \lipsum[2][1-3]\\
\end{tabularx}

%X as m-column:
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{llX}
  \multirow{1}{*}{A} & B & \lipsum[1][1-2] \\
                     & C & \lipsum[2][1-3]\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To center the A over both cells use a value of 8.5 or 9 works (that's the number of lines below the baseline of the first cell.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{llX}
  \multirow{9}{*}{A} & B & \lipsum[1][1-2] \\
                     & C & \lipsum[2][1-3]\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the improvement? Apparently I was not clear in my question, but by nicely I mean "A" centred vertically in the middle of the table. I updated my question.

Comment: Ah sorry, I added an edit.

Comment: Now there are 6 lines above and 5 below "A". `7` works for me. This solution requires a tedious counting  of lines manually.

Comment: Yes, but the A is aligned to a line. It is up to you to decide what is visual more pleasing. And yes, it is a pain - I already wrote in the answer. I wouldn't use multirow but nested tabulars or even simple boxes for such a layout.

Comment: it could be worthwhile to provide your solution with nested tabulars or simple boxes.