# Vertical alignment of equations

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'm trying to put three equations in the same line.

I used the `tabularx` package as was advised by this post:  [How to place and number 3 short equations in one line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33433/how-to-place-and-number-3-short-equations-in-one-line).

However since I am using equation with different heights, they do not align well vertically.

I manage to solve this using `\vspace` but I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution. Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  \vspace{0.1mm}
  \begin{equation}
    Euc(P,Q)= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \left| p_i - q_i \right|^2 \right)^{1/2}
    \label{eqn:1}
  \end{equation} &
  \vspace{1.5mm}
  \begin{equation}
    Canb(P,Q)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{|p_i-q_i|}{|p_i|+|q_i|}
    \label{eqn:2}
  \end{equation} &
  \vspace{5.8mm}
  \begin{equation}
    Man(P,Q)=\sum_{i=1}^n |p_i-q_i|
    \label{eqn:3}
  \end{equation}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Two equation numbers in the same row are bad style; three are … `;-)` The line is very cluttered and makes it difficult to see the numbers themselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To place three numbered equations next to one another, you could use the `multicols` environment, which is provided by the `multicol` package. In the example below, using this environment makes it unnecessary to fiddle with various tabular-like environments or experiment with `\vspace` adjustments.

[image]

Incidentally, using `\left(` ... `\right)` to enclose a summation symbol with limits tends to generate parentheses that are far too large, typographically speaking. Better to use `\biggl(` ... `\biggr)` in such cases. (This is not only my prescription; you may find it in the TeXbook as well.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,multicol}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Euc}{Euc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Canb}{Canb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Man}{Man}
\usepackage[margin=0.4in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{equation}
\Euc(P,Q)= \biggl( \sum_{i=1}^n \abs{ p_i - q_i }^2 \biggr)^{1/2}
    \label{eqn:1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\Canb(P,Q)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\abs{p_i-q_i}}{\abs{p_i}+\abs{q_i}}
    \label{eqn:2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\Man(P,Q)=\sum_{i=1}^n \abs{p_i-q_i}
    \label{eqn:3}
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about the multicol package. Thank you for the parenthesis tip as well!

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do doesn't look nice IMHO; I would just use

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Euc}{Euc}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Canb}{Canb}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Man}{Man}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \label{eqn:1}
  \Euc(P,Q)  &= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \abs*{p_i - q_i}^2\right)^{\mkern -6mu 1/2},\\
 \label{eqn:2}
  \Canb(P,Q) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\abs*{p_i - q_i}}{\abs*{p_i} + \abs*{q_i}},\\
 \label{eqn:3}
  \Man(P,Q)  &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \abs*{p_i - q_i}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Sorry, but the first code example that I posted was wrong, so you would get a very ugly layout indeed. Please see the corrected example.