# Subequations in one line with clubbed numbering

Tags: math-mode, equations, subequations

I am trying to write a bunch of short equations (subequations, actually) in a single line, and have their numbering clubbed and mentioned at the side end, mentioning them as a range for three or more equations.

Something like this:[image: Equation: example]

So far, I found how to write the equations in one line with individual numbering beside each:
[How to place and number 3 short equations in one line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33433/how-to-place-and-number-3-short-equations-in-one-line)

But didn't quite get what I am looking for.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please always provide *minimal workinf example* (mwe), a small complete document beginning with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}` which we can copy and test. with this you will help us to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i correctly understood you, than you looking for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}\label{eq:1}
2=1+1
\end{gather}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:2}
\begin{gather}
2=1+1,   \quad   2=1+1,   \quad   2=1+1,    \tag{\theequation a-c} \\
2=1+1,   \quad   2=1+1,                     \tag{\theequation d,e}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
\begin{gather}\label{eq:3}
2=1+1
\end{gather}
see \eqref{eq:1}, \eqref{eq:2} and \eqref{eq:3}, however sub-equations letters you need to add manually: (\ref{eq:2}a) and (\ref{eq:2}d).
\end{document}
```